# PostgreSQL CONTAINS operator (@>) in CakePHP?

Tags: php, postgresql, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

Wondering if CakePHP supports the [CONTAINS operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html)

The query I have in Postgres is something like:

```
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE name @> '{matthew}'::text[]
```

Where accounts.name is populated with arrays containing name values. e.g. `{matthew, john, susy}`

Anybody know how to implement this in CakePHP?

Comment: what version of cake?

Comment: Sorry, version is 2.x.